# Possibility of using multiple CRAN mirrors? [RStudio]

Tags: r, rstudio, cran

I've spent the last 4 hours trying to find out why I wasn't able to install any packages in `R` (it started with me trying to install a package I was developing). It would just stall for +5 minutes without doing anything or outputting anything to the terminal. I tracked the issue down to the following call:

```r
repos <- structure("https://cran.rstudio.com/", .Names = "CRAN")
type <- "both"
utils::available.packages(utils::contrib.url(repos, type), type = type)
```

I realized after a while that it was just the RStudio CRAN mirror, and when I changed the repo to "https://cran.case.edu/", it started working. However, there was literally no indication of this on the surface--and it took *forever* for me to  find out what the problem was.

My question is this: **Is there a way of using *multiple* CRAN repos so when one fails, others are used?**  Or at least a way that will prevent this from happening again?

Comment: You should be able to use character vector of mirror urls, and just don't set the name.

Comment: And that will default from one to the other down the line, essentially?

Comment: it will use both at the same time AFAIK